# How do I connect my PHP code to Heroku's addon 'SendGrid'?

Tags: php, composer-php

I purchased a template that included a PHP contact form using AJAX I'm using Heroku to deploy my web application,(my portfolio), and SendGrid as my add-on in order to send API-driven emails from my portfolio. When I submit my form, I get a '500: Internal Server Error', so my question is, how to I integrate SendGrid into the PHP code I already have?

I'm unfamiliar with PHP and during research I did download composer and these files were automated:
- A vender folder 
-composer.json file
-composer.lock file

Here is my Repo: https://github.com/Mendiolac/Portfolio
Here is my Portfolio link: https://cm-portfolio.herokuapp.com/

I tried the SMTP route where SendGrip gives you the steps to configure your application by connecting it their server and when I tested it was unsuccessful without an error message.

```
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

  if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
    die('Sorry Request must be Ajax POST');
  }

  if(isset($_POST)) {

    $name = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $subject = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
    $message = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if(!$contact_email_to || $contact_email_to == 'contact@example.com') {
      die('The contact form receiving email address is not configured!');
    }

    if(strlen($name)<3){
      die($contact_error_name);
    }

    if(!$email){
      die($contact_error_email);
    }

    if(strlen($subject)<3){
      die($contact_error_subject);
    }

    if(strlen($message)<3){
      die($contact_error_message);
    }

    if(!isset($contact_email_from)) {
      $contact_email_from = "contactform@" . @preg_replace('/^www\./','', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
    }

    $headers = 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $contact_email_from . '>' . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $email . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $message_content = '<strong>' . $name_title . '</strong> ' . $name . '<br>';
    $message_content .= '<strong>' . $email_title . '</strong> ' . $email . '<br>';
    $message_content .= '<strong>' . $message_title . '</strong> ' . nl2br($message);

    $sendemail = mail($contact_email_to, $subject_title . ' ' . $subject, $message_content, $headers);

    if( $sendemail ) {
      echo 'OK';
    } else {
      echo 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.';
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it correctly on https://github.com/Mendiolac/Portfolio/commit/0ad2fc815523a26f272f91bb192123c4caf41632 , just need to add keys to your .env file

Comment: I just want to clarify, by keys, do you mean adding specific Ports and the Server to the .env file?

Comment: Yes port along with username/password or API key